# Alias or Intercept complex bash command with args

Tags: bash

How do you create a bash alias for a command with flags? <strike>For example, if I run `ls -l`, I want that to alias to `ls -a`.</strike>

This doesn't work:  `alias "ls -l"="ls -a"`

Another example: If I type `reboot now`, I want that to simply run `reboot`.

Would bash functions be useful here?

---

EDIT: Sorry for the silly `ls -l` example. This is what I really want: if you executed `reboot now`, I want it to actually execute `reboot`. [This is why.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139160)

Comment: The real question is why? Why bother typing `ls -l` if you want `ls -a`?

Comment: True, that was a silly example. The real reason is that on recent versions of Ubuntu, the command `reboot now` takes the machine down for maintenance, which is bad if you're SSHed into a remote VM and can't manually reboot it. I wanted to intercept all `reboot now` commands and change them to `reboot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Another example: If I type `reboot now`, I want that to simply run `reboot`.

Create a function:

```
reboot() {
  command reboot
}
```

Now invoking the command `reboot` would invoke the function `reboot` which would ignore all parameters passed to it.

That is:

```
reboot
```

and

```
reboot now
```

would execute the command `reboot` (without any argument).

Answer (score 4):

You should just alias `ls`:

```
alias ls='ls -a'
```

after that, if you do `ls -l` it will result in  `ls -la`

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. Maybe I shouldn't have used such a simplistic example. I'd like to know how (or if it's possible) to alias a general command with given flags or arguments.

Answer (score 3):

> This is what I really want: if you executed `reboot now`, I want it to actually execute `reboot`.

Find out the absolute path of `reboot` (e.g., via `whereis reboot`). 
Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in $PATH before that (it probably is already).<sup>1</sup>  Now create a `/usr/local/sbin/reboot` file that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

reboot
```

That should be owned by root and `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/reboot`.  From now on, by default

```
reboot whatever, blah-blah
```

will just invoke `reboot` with no arguments.

<sup>1. If not, see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124444/how-can-i-cleanly-add-to-path/).</sup>