# -bash: android: command not found

Tags: bash, path, android

I'm on a Mac running Mavericks trying to learn how to develop Android apps (in the process I'm learning bash too).

To [run on the emulator](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) they suggest the command `android avd`.

I always get the error in the title of this post.  I've searched all over and the issue seems to lie with changing the PATH.

I've amended .bash_profile as such:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 export PATH=/development/dev_android/sdk/tools:$PATH`

but it's still not working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked `$PATH` to make sure it's actually set the way you want it to be (`echo $PATH`)?  Simply adding things to `~/.bash_profile` does not mean it's actually been sourced by your shell.

Comment: @goldilocks: you're correct it has not been sourced by my shell.  Any tips on how to make that happen?

Comment: I just realized after @goldilocks comments that I never restarted the terminal.  After restarting the terminal it found the path and I was able to use the command `android avd'.

Comment: You can simply `source ~/.bash_profile`.  That file is usually only sourced when you log in, and not when you start a new shell or open a new terminal (but OSX may implement its own additional rules).  INVOCATION under `man bash` explains this. You may also be interested **[in this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124444/how-can-i-cleanly-add-to-path)**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969753/android-command-not-found