# How do I create a user bin directory in gentoo

Tags: bash, gentoo

I would like gentoo to allow users to have a bin directory which is added to the PATH variable for that user. The directory would be located at /home/user/bin.

Where is the best place to set the PATH variable to this directory for each user?

Comment: Every user should have a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file in their home directory. Add `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` to the file you choose to use.

Comment: Worth a glance, particularly if you use `.bashrc`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124444/25985 Note that which startup files are sourced depends on how the user logs in and there is no singular, universal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into `/etc/profile`. The best place to do this is in `/etc/profile.d`. Place a script in this directory that looks like this:

```
# add ~/bin to path for all users.
PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

When `/etc/profile` runs it calls

```
for sh in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
        [ -r "$sh" ] && . "$sh"
done
```

This will run the new script in `/etc/profile.d`.

The advantage of this in gentoo is when `/etc/profile` is updated through emerge there will be no `dispatch-conf` changes that need to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply to each user, you can do what danemacmillan has said.

But if you want to apply to a system wide, especially for newly created users, you have to modify the file **/etc/skel/.bashrc**
with these following lines:

**export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"**

Have fun!

Comment: Note that this won't make any difference for existing users. Modifying `/etc/profile` is probably an option.