# Add path to $PATH if not already in $PATH

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, path

I need to add a path in a `bash` script, but it may be executed several times:

```
export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin/:${PATH}
```

I don't want that path to be added over and over. How can I add it if it is not in `$PATH` yet?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First check if the path to add is already part of the variable:

```
[[ ":$PATH:" != *":/path/to/add:"* ]] && PATH="/path/to/add:${PATH}"
```

If `/path/to/add` is already in the `$PATH`, then nothing happens, else it is added at the beginning.

If you need it at the end use `PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/add` instead.

**Edit**: In you case it would look like this:

```
[[ ":$PATH:" != *":${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin:"* ]] && PATH="${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Can I write it like this? [[ ":$PATH:" != *"${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin/"* ]] && PATH="${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin/:${PATH}" ? Sorry, I am no expert with unix scripting...

Comment: @JVerstry See my edited answer

Comment: The colons before and after on both sides of the equals are for when adding a prefix of something already in PATH, e.g. adding '/home' when '/home/chaos/bin' is already present. Otherwise, the comparison would incorrectly say that '/home' was already present.

Comment: It took me a minute to realize that this does indeed work even when the target path is the first or last in the $PATH. That's because you wrap the $PATH in colons before testing. Just thought I'd point that out in case anyone else pondered the same.

Answer (score 30):

The sysadmin in my old lab had a nifty little function for this:

```
pathmunge () {
        if ! echo "$PATH" | /bin/grep -Eq "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
           if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
              PATH="$PATH:$1"
           else
              PATH="$1:$PATH"
           fi
        fi
}
```

It will both check whether the string given is already in the `PATH` and also lets you add it to the end or the beginning as desired:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ pathmunge /sbin/             ## Add to the start; default
$ echo $PATH
/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ pathmunge /usr/sbin/ after   ## Add to the end
$ echo $PATH
/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/
```

I have this function in my `~/.profile` and use it to modify my `$PATH`.

Comment: Wonder who's the original author of this particular function. It's kinda ubiquitous.

Comment: @DeerHunter yeah, I've seen it around. All I know is that it's not mine and that my ex sysadmin gave it to me. Whether or not it's his is another matter :). It's pretty straightforward though, I'm sure many people have written this or a very similar approach independently.

Comment: if using bash (v3.0 or later) may be cleaner to `if [[ "${X}" =~ (^|:)${1}($|:) ]] ; ...`

Comment: Assume `grep` is on the path, since `/bin/grep` might not be universal installation path.

Comment: @DarrenWeber if grep isn't in /bin/grep you can use the right path for it. But this is extremely unlikely, and I don't want to assume anything in the very function used to set up the PATH. That would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If it's the same string, then just do it:

```sh
set -a -- "$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/runtime/bin/"
PATH=$1:${PATH#"$1:"}
set +a --
```

You can do that over and over and the value of `$PATH` won't change.

Alternatively you can check for it.

```sh
set -a -- "$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/runtime/bin/"
case :${PATH:=$1}: in
(*:"$1":*) ;; (*)
    PATH=$1:$PATH
esac;  set +a --
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed you can do it by

```
echo ${PATH} | 
    sed "\|${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin|\
        ! s|^|export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin:|e"
```