# Shouldn't the first export PATH be without :$PATH

Tags: path

What I noticed is that when I add a `:$PATH` to the first `PATH`, it repeats all the path when you `echo` it.

I use the `MANPATH` for example, but the same thing happens with the `PATH` variable.

```
# I use MANPATH here
export MANPATH="/usr/local/share/man" # Here no :$MANPATH
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
```

This outputs:

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/share/man
```

But when I add `:$MANPATH` to the first one:

```
export MANPATH="/usr/local/share/man:$MANPATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
```

This outputs:

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/share/man:
```

As you see, all the MANPATH are repeated.

So my questions are:

1. Should I omit the `:$PATH` or `$MANPATH` at the end of the first line?
2. Why it repeats all the paths when I add it to the end of the first line?

Comment: Just a comment: You only ever need a single `export` to make a shell variable an environment variable. Exporting it in every assignment is not needed. You don't need to export variables that already are environment variables, like `PATH` (unless you `unset` them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, when you run

```bsh
export MANPATH="/usr/local/share/man:$MANPATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
```

you end up with the content of `MANPATH` being

```
/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/share/man:
```

it means that `MANPATH` already contained

```
/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/share/man:
```

before the first assignment (i.e. you did not start with a new/empty variable).

As you are showing, `foo=bar:$foo` means "concatenate the string `foo` currently expands to to 'bar' and assign the result to `foo`". You *reset* the `foo` variable if you start a series of assignments with `foo=bar`; you *extend* `foo` if you start with `foo=bar:$foo`.

Coming to the question asked in the title, whether you should use `foo=bar` (reset) or `foo=bar:$foo` (extend) depends on the context. Usually, shell profile files that add paths to `PATH` are meant to only run once per user session. The more conservative choice they can do is to extend `PATH`, because other programs may have added useful components to it before they run.

If a shell script needs to ensure it only extends an environment variable once, regardless of how many times it is run, it needs to check whether the variable already contains the to-be-added component. For more on this, see [How can I cleanly add to $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124444/315749)

Answer (score 1):

Doing `MANPATH="/path/to/somewhere:$MANPATH"` means "add `/path/to/somewhere` to `PATH`".
Doing `MANPATH="/path/to/somewhere"` means "erase whatever `MANPATH` stores and set it to `/path/to/somewhere`"
Whether you should do it or not depends on it you want to *overwrite* or *append to* the `MANPATH` variable.